# Is it useful to flag comments on a deleted question as offensive?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, deleted-questions

Somebody posted rude and offensive comments on their own question, reacting to one of my comments. A while later, they deleted the question. I have only noticed the comments after the post has been deleted.

I have the necessary reputation to see deleted posts and the comments are technically not deleted. The "flag" option still seems to be active. I wonder if I should use it? I don't want to create extra work for the moderators and I know I should just shrug it off, but if such flags are somehow accumulated for the perpetrator I would certainly like to make an official note of their bad behavior.

Comment: I witnessed the comments of that particular question. IIRC (I don't have enough rep to view deleted questions so I couldn't verify) the same user shows some strange behavior (not offensive) today at another question. Maybe that is of some interest to you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from nuking profanity-laden comments with rude/offensive flags, but because they're one-shot flags they handle themselves automatically without us ever seeing them.

If you're looking to raise a user's bad behavior to our attention (which is something we always appreciate, so don't feel like you're creating unnecessary work for us), that will be counter-productive; instead, your best bet is to flag the post with a custom flag, telling us why you think we should keep an eye on the user. We always see those, and they never go away automatically.

If you're not looking to get a moderator involved, I'd opine that your time and flags are better spent on things that are publicly visible, than on things that nobody outside of 10k users will even get to see anyway. (This is one reason why viewing of deleted posts is part of the "moderation tools" privilege.)

Comment: I don't see this one-shot behavior explained in [How does comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/195099). It only says that a comment with certain keywords may need fewer flags, but doesn't clarify if a single flag is enough.

Comment: @Oriol: They apparently wanted to keep the exact numbers secret, but being that these are comment flags I'm not sure I see the point.

Answer (score 14):

Fear not :) If there is vulgarity in a comment and you flag it as rude or offensive it is instantly deleted without wasting moderator time.

If it is just rude in general then that would be a different scenario, but still worth flagging in my opinion. If you can view something that offends you, feel free to flag it.

At the very least, this will provide information about the behavior you are observing - these metrics are recorded for future use.