# Ask a question, get the needed help, insult the helper and delete the question: what to do?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-questions, rude-or-abusive

Am gonna share a situation I recently faced (that I also faced a lot of time before). It's about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717078/hide-object-until-animated-keyframe-slide-fade-css-animation) *(deleted now)*.

**Here is what happened:**

This user asked a question about CSS and animation, there is nothing bad in the question but the question is (for me) cleary off topic simply because *"This question was caused by a simple typographical error"*. We can notice this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5y78Lpes/1/). We can clearly see that we have syntax errors that we can easily fix by simply checking the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

So I voted to close it as I don't think it deserves an answer BUT I also commented in order to help the user getting his issue fixed.

By the way this user was very ungrateful and a bit rude with me and when I made the effort to share the final correct code with him, he insulted me with very bad words and then deleted his question (maybe thinking that we can no more see it). Of course, his insult got deleted by the system before I can get a screenshot of it, but am pretty sure a moderator can still see it.

**What to do in such situation?**

The question got deleted and the bad comment got deleted too.

Should I simply move on and forget? Should I flag such behavior somewhere as a bad behavior?

By the way, it's not the first time. I always face such situation especially when closing as duplicate. The asker don't even take the time to read the duplicate question and start complaining and being rude. And when they get downvoted, they are upset thinking that the one who's commenting is the downvoter even if they get many downvotes and even if their issue is being fixed by a comment or in the duplicate question.

Why people are giving a lot of importance to downvotes and/or their closed questions when at the end they have the needed answer (either by a comment or within the duplicate question)?

Should we also give importance to such behavior in order to limit them? Or we simply don't care as most of the question involved in such situation will get deleted either by the asker or by votes.

**UPDATE**

Of course, if the user will repeat the same action again and again, I will flag for sure (as I did before) but should I give importance to such **isolated case**? I face them many times but rarely with the same user. For me they are a lot but for this *bad* user it can be the first time BUT maybe he did the same with other users and no one flagged him before.

---

Some related questions where I did not find the needed answer:
• [What should I do about a user that I'm trying to help and is calling me stupid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296913/what-should-i-do-about-a-user-that-im-trying-to-help-and-is-calling-me-stupid)
• [Is it useful to flag comments on a deleted question as offensive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322500/is-it-useful-to-flag-comments-on-a-deleted-question-as-offensive)

Comment: Broader encompassing issue: how to rid the world of jerks. I don't know of any decent solution unfortunately. I can only hope that karma catches up to him.

Comment: My advice to that second question applies just as well here. If you're concerned that this user might become a problem to other users in the future, let us know, we'll keep an eye on them. If not, well, some people are ungrateful pricks, it's life.

Comment: @BoltClock ok, and are you able to see his deleted bad comment ? i  want to be sure that a moderator can still see automatic deleted comments so that i know there is a proof of his bad behavior if he will be doing the same next time.

Comment: Yes, don't worry.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the rude comment, but just a point about the typo close reason; the close reason says that the question "was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." Just being a simple typographical error doesn't mean they don't deserve a response if the question is well written, the way it's phrased in in past tense, assuming that now that the issue has been resolved, it is ready to be closed because it won't help others. I can't see the question, so you might be right that it didn't deserve an answer, but generally we help then close for these.

Comment: *Why people are giving a lot of importance to downvotes and/or their closed questions when at the end they have the needed answer (either by a comment or within the duplicate question)?* A phrase I keep seeing when people protest these actions is "It's a legitimate question" which makes me think that people think the moderation on the site is (or should) only be used to stop spam and trolling.

Comment: @DavyM `I can't see the question` --> and you cannot see the comments also :) and the rude one that is only visible to moderator ... the issue is not with the question, someone can answer it, it's only my thought if i consider it as off topic .. BUT my concerns was about the behavior of the person. I closed the question but i commented to give him the correct code that he needs, thus the reason he deleted his question but he insulted me before deleting.

Comment: related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Comment: Not sure what I was expecting when I clicked the link to the deleted question....

Comment: Why do you say that you can't flag the question? You have >10k reputation, so can see deleted posts. You can flag deleted posts (i.e. the question) for moderator attention. You can also flag the comments on deleted posts (or at least the flag dialog opens; I didn't actually try flagging a comment, so don't know for sure that it's effective).

Comment: @Makyen yes true maybe i didn't write it well but my concerns is not the possibility to flag or not to flag BUT does it deserve flagging since the bad comment got already deleted and the question also deleted ?... Of course when the question stay open i will for sure flag (as i did before) but what about such case? should i bother myself for something that is removed and no one will see it or should i simply move on?

Comment: I almost agree with BoltClock on this one. I think that you should flag a moderator about that, because I don't think that this user (or any other user, for that matter) is only going to be rude and offensive to you specifically. You just need to remember two things: 1 - Remember that user and never try to help him again, and 2 - Rude and offensive strangers on the internet is practically unavoidable in this day and age. You simply need to remind yourself that some people are jerks and that have nothing to do with you.

Comment: The problem of the deleted questions after the first answer, and the insulting lowrep commenters, are completely different problems. I can't see any reason to close this question as dupe (although it may be a dupe of a different question, as far I remember, this topic happens not the first time here).

Comment: If neither of the proposed duplicates answers your specific question, *what exactly is your specific question?*

Comment: There's a [userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script)  that lets you blacklist users and hides them. So you don't have to remember them at all...

Comment: @tripleee, in the first question the user is trying to help the new user to improve his question but in my case i helped the user to fix his issue and i gave him the answer even if his question is off-topic. The second one deal with flagging a comment as offensive but in my case the comment got deleted ---> so my real question is does it matter to try to flag/report such behavior even if the question and comment got deleted ? should i bother myself to flag something no one will see? when the comment or the question are still visible it's clear that i need to flag but in this case i don't know.

Comment: That sounds like exactly the second duplicate to me, can you clarify how it's not?

Comment: @tripleee i understand from the second question that the comments are still there even if the question is deleted ... so we still have something *bad* to flag ... but in my case if you look to the question, there is no bad comments so should i flag the question to say that "i got insulted but it's already removed ?" maybe if i do it will get declined as "it's already deleted so there is nothing to do" ... so flagging should concerns only visible things or can i also do the same even if nothing is no more visible?

Comment: @tripleee so saying bad things and insulting then deleting them is also consider as bad behavior but should they be flagged somewhere or not ? or since everything is deleted, we simply move on?

Comment: The accepted answer on the second duplicate says to raise a custom moderator flag if you feel the behavior warrants this. What other answer could you possibly hope for ...?

Comment: @tripleee well let's say that am looking for answers like "Yes you should always flag this with no doubt as bad behavior even for the first time" as said in the previous question OR "some people are like that, so no need to waste your time and move on, do it only if it get repeated many times" ---> And as i see in the comments most people agree with the second option, so maybe i don't have to bother myself with lonely cases even if i face them many times but with different users.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: So you... don't quite agree after all? :(

Comment: @BoltClock I agree with your first comment almost entirely, I only disagree about one point - you wrote "If you're concerned that this user might become a problem to other users in the future" - IMHO, I don't think there's a place for that "if" - A user that acts this way to another will also act this way to other users.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: Fair enough.

Comment: @BoltClock Now it's killing me what's in that deleted comment. :) Is it like the deleted answers here?

Comment: @Mysticial All the comments I saw from the other user were just swearing and insults. They also said they were going to keep at it until they either lost all their rep or got banned so they could blog about how toxic the community is.

Answer (score 11):

It's worth a flag if they go out of their way to insult or hurl abuse at you, since that'll at least get them on the moderators' radar.  I will note that I saw nothing of the sort in this exchange, which is puzzling...maybe a diamond moderator can see more than we can here.

However...I want to call attention to this remark you made.

> So I voted to close it as I don't think it deserves an answer BUT I also commented in order to help the user getting his issue fixed.

If you think the question should be closed, **you do not believe that any answers provided by yourself or the community can help.**

If you think the question should be answered, **you do not believe that there are problems with the question OR that the duplicate doesn't apply.**

You should not have half-engaged in this situation; it's very much the case that if this were a typographic error, **you should have left it at that** and not responded in any capacity.

It also doesn't bode *that* well [for your response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717078/hide-object-until-animated-keyframe-slide-fade-css-animation#comment86447283_49717078):

> here is your answer jsfiddle.net/rbamay50/3 ... shame on me that am trying to help and i fixed your issue within my first comment, but of course who cares !! askers always complaining when we trying to help them and they don't like we they get downvoted for their question, you don't even know who downvoted your question !! and you are pretty sure it's me .. nevermind, i will keep you on mind and avoid helping you next time ;)

Saying that in a comment doesn't have you coming out like an innocent party in all of this.  You both *might* have antagonized each other in a way and you both walked away feeling disgruntled about the whole engagement.  Next time, you should *simply* walk away if you don't feel like the question should remain open.

Comment: well, since he's banned now am gonna answer you ;) . First there is two part : there is this website where we have rules and there  the real word ... The question doesn't deserve an answer and am still conviced about this and i know it will get closed/deleted but i thought it was good to help this person in his real world so he get his issue fixed and he can continue his life and i did this in my second comments BUT the user start complaining about logical downvotes he was getting even if he already had the answser and he has not idea who downvoted.

Comment: and i never came here as an innocent and am aware about my comment and is there anythin rude in it ? i don't think so, because if it was it will get deleted ... I commented twice to show him his issue and this was the third one where i added a full answer and i was upset because we was talking aboud downvotes, etc ... He can also reply to this comment if he want i have no issue but he start insulting me and i never insulted him

Comment: as a side note : i was not especially concerned with this question or this person i created this thread in general to ask what to do in such situation as i faced them a lot ... this particular user did the same thing today with someone else and i was there so i flagged him and he's banned now ... and you saw how he's behaving, being rude and insulting everyone with no reason

Comment: ...Again, somehow this magically justifies the comment you left behind @TemaniAfif?  I'm not saying that they weren't in the wrong, but I'm not saying that you were in the right, either.  When it's clear that the conversation gets heated, then it's clear you shouldn't be engaging.

Comment: Also, you keep saying that this question doesn't deserve an answer yet you left an answer anyway.  I'm not sure why you keep thinking that leaving an answer in comments is somehow not the same as leaving an answer.

Comment: `you keep saying that this question doesn't deserve an answer yet you left an answer anyway` --> yes in this website it doens't deserve an answer as am not going to add an answer here as such question won't be a good ressource for SO but i thought it was good before the question got closed/deleted to tell him about his issue, to help him but i will never do this again.

Comment: You're *literally* contradicting yourself.  The question wasn't deserving of an answer, but the question was deserving of an answer.  It'd be good for you to take a moment to really think about this angle.

Comment: well let's make it easy : "someone is asking about good website to find tutorial"  ---> should i answer to tell him "here is a good website" . No, as the question is clearly off topic BUT is it bad to comment with links if i know them in order to help this person ? The person is asking for a help in the wrong place so his question doesn't deserve an answer in this website... exactly like this one, am not going to answer to tell him he has a typo in his code. I should close it and go away BUT i did the effort to tel him in the comment where is his error thinking am doing good.

Comment: i don't know if am clear enought but what i meant is that it's bad to answer such answer, get upvote and accepted answer ... we don't need this record on the website ... but if i comment to help him, we have no record, we simply wait until by votes the question is closed and that's it ... i guess you faced such situation many times ... the first comment giving the error and getting upvotes and in few minutes the question closed as typo issue --> then later deleted

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  Yeah, I'm not sure how you're mixing this up...but if a question is not worth answering, then it's not worth commenting on, even *if* you believe it'd "help" their cause.  You're only reinforcing the idea that Stack Overflow is a place to ask those kinds of questions and still get a response.  If the question is off-topic, close it.  That's all you should be doing.  No comments.  No helpful hints.  Just *close it*.

Comment: @Temani: I would offer some general feedback on your commenting. Your posts seem to be very well written and formatted, but your comments seem to be written either on a mobile phone or in lower-case purely for aesthetic reasons. It's worth remembering that low-rep users will look to you as an example of behaviour on Stack Overflow, and we get enough low-quality posts as it is. If you can use upper case for "I" and at the start of sentences, that would be great. Use italics for emphasis, not all-caps. Use an English spell-checker to avoid typos (your browser may have one built in).

Comment: @halfer yes true, i don't give a lot of importance to comments :) i only pay attention when i write posts (question/answer) as these are the main ressources, comment are secondary [my thoughts by the way] and if i had to correctly write each comment it would take me a lot of time and effort as english is not my native langage :/

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I would give way on grammar, but case and spelling are trivial to fix. Case is easy to remember, and spelling can be fixed with a spell checker. Again, you are setting an example, whether you intend to or not. We get a lot of deliberately stylised lower-case on the site, and the phenomenon probably stems from chatrooms and mobile-phone texting. It's not appropriate for a technical resource site.

Comment: "If you think the question should be closed, you do not believe that any answers provided by yourself or the community can help." This is not true. The obvious example is recommendation questions. A lot of us could provide recommendations for libraries, books, etc., but we don't because it was decided these don't make long term valuable resources.